# Calculating a week beginning date in Python, starting on Monday

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with  columns 'Transaction_Date' and 'Day_of_Week'. The former is a datetime64 format, the latter the day of the week spelled out. I'm trying to create a separate column called 'Week_of', which begins on Mondays.  Specifically, if a row's 'Transaction_Date' has a 'Day_of_Week' of Monday, then I want 'Week_of' to be the same as 'Transaction_Date'. If it's Tuesday, then 'Week_of' is 'Transaction_Date' - 1 day; minus 2 days if Wednesday, and so on.

I've tried this code:

```
'''
Determine day of week
'''
df['Day_of_Week']=df['Transaction_Date'].dt.strftime('%A')

'''
Determine Week of Date
'''

# Create a value for Week_of date
if df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Monday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]
elif df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Tuesday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=1)
elif df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Wednesday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=2)
elif df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Thursday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=3)
elif df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Friday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=4)
elif df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Saturday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=5)
else:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]-dt.timedelta(days=6)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's why this is a problem.

```
# Create a value for Week_of date
if df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Monday']:
    df['Week_of'] = df[df['Transaction_Date']]
```

There are (probably) many rows where "Day_of_Week" is "Monday".  So, what is the `if` statement supposed to check?  How does it come up with one true/false decision?  And the assignment statement there affects EVERY row.

You need to use smart indexing.  `df['Day_of_week']=='Monday'` return an array with the rows where that expression is true.  You can just use that to select the rows to change:

```
df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Monday']['Week_of'] = df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Monday']['Transaction_Date']]
df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Tuesday']['Week_of'] = df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Tuesday']['Transaction_Date']] - dt.timedelta(days=1)
df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Wednesday']['Week_of'] = df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Wednesday']['Transaction_Date']] - dt.timedelta(days=2)
df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Thursday']['Week_of'] = df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Thursday']['Transaction_Date']] - dt.timedelta(days=3)
df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Friday']['Week_of'] = df[df['Day_of_Week']=='Friday']['Transaction_Date']] - dt.timedelta(days=4)
```

So, reading that, "for those rows where Day_of_Week is Tuesday, set the value to the Transaction_Date column minus 1 day".

This is probably not the best way to handle this.  `apply` might even be better.